# Div em forma de gráfico

Tags: html, css, front-end, gráfico

Boa tarde. Estou desenvolvendo um projeto em front-end, experiência nova.

Preciso criar um "gráfico", em formato ranking. Porém, as divs se iniciam de cima para baixo, preciso inverter isso. Como faço? Meu código está abaixo.

Obrigado.

```css
.rank-1 {
 background-color: #8ccfc3;
 margin-left: 30px;
 height: 190px;
 
}

.rank-2 {
 background-color: #8ccfc3;
 margin-left: 30px;
 height: 150px;
 
}

.rank-3 {
 background-color: #8ccfc3;
 margin-left: 30px;
 height: 210px;
 
}

.rank-4 {
 background-color: #8ccfc3;
 margin-left: 30px;
 height: 230px;
 
}

.rank-5 {
 background-color: #8ccfc3;
 margin-left: 30px;
 height: 170px;
 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
   <div class="ranking">
   <div class="row container-fluid">
     <div class="col-1 rank-1"></div>
     <div class="col-1 rank-2"></div>
     <div class="col-1 rank-3"></div>
     <div class="col-1 rank-4"></div>
     <div class="col-1 rank-5"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como vc está usando Bootstrap 4 vc pode usar a classe flex align-items-end, isso vai alinhar as Col na base da Row, já que ela já é um container flex. Link da documentação flex do Bootstrap 4 https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

Veja

```css
.rank-1 {
  background-color: #8ccfc3;
  margin-left: 30px;
  height: 190px;
  
}

.rank-2 {
  background-color: #8ccfc3;
  margin-left: 30px;
  height: 150px;
  
}

.rank-3 {
  background-color: #8ccfc3;
  margin-left: 30px;
  height: 210px;
  
}

.rank-4 {
  background-color: #8ccfc3;
  margin-left: 30px;
  height: 230px;
  
}

.rank-5 {
  background-color: #8ccfc3;
  margin-left: 30px;
  height: 170px;
  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="ranking">
    <div class="row container-fluid align-items-end">
        <div class="col-1 rank-1"></div>
        <div class="col-1 rank-2"></div>
        <div class="col-1 rank-3"></div>
        <div class="col-1 rank-4"></div>
        <div class="col-1 rank-5"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! <3

Comment: @JoaoPedro valeu garoto!